# What is the purpose of Celery's "autodiscover_tasks" function?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm wondering what is the purpose of Celery's `autodiscover_tasks` function. Im am using Celery 4.1.2 with Django 2.1.4.

The Celery documentation refers to imports:

> `foo.tasks` and `bar.tasks` being imported

But I can't comprehend how this works.

All the examples I found on GitHub [including this one from the Official Celery repo](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django), rely on manually importing (i.e.`from demoapp.tasks import add, mul, xsum`) the tasks even when calling the `autodiscover_tasks` function when booting the worker.

I guess this is how Python work, you can't access to classes "globally", like in Ruby, for example.

Then once again, what is this function for? I'm no expert at Celery and maybe I am missing something. The only thing I see is the name of the discovered tasks when launching the Celery worker, is that all this function is supposed to do?

Thanks for your inputs,

Answer (score 9):

When using celery with django, the `autodiscover_tasks` function registers all decorated tasks within the task module inside each `INSTALLED_APPS` entry.  e.g.,

if your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings included app1, app2, and app3, celery would automatically register any decorated tasks that could be found by looking at `app1.tasks`, `app2.tasks`, and `app3.tasks`.